# Jenkins Connector in Mule

Tags: jenkins, mule, mule-component, cloudhub

I am new to Mule and I want to understand how to use the Jenkins Connector in Anypoint Studio to build and run any job on the Jenkins Server. I want to deploy an application on anypoint cloudhub, so please share you ideas about the Jenkins Connector, how it will be useful for build and other stuff.

Comment: Cleanup up syntax.

Comment: **@rlandster**, Please explain exactly what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following link which has he details on Jenkins connector operations.

http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-platform-dev/automate-your-deployments-with-the-jenkins-api/

Hope this helps